# typescript class decorator: override the constructor but preserve the class name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

The typescript handbook has an example of how to use a class decorator to override the constructor ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators)):

```js
function classDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  return class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
  };
}

@classDecorator
class Greeter {
  property = "property";
  hello: string;
  constructor(m: string) {
    this.hello = m;
  }
}
```

When I log out an instance of the resulting class, the class name is missing:

```js
console.log(new Greeter("world"));
//=> { "property": "property", "hello": "override", "newProperty": "new property" }
```

Now, if I modify the decorator to assign the the new class to a variable, the log will contain the name of that variable:

```js
function classDecorator2<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  const MyDecoratedClass = class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
  };
  return MyDecoratedClass
}


@classDecorator2
class Greeter2 {
  // ... same as Greeter
}


console.log(new Greeter2("world"));
//=> MyDecoratedClass: { "property": "property", "hello": "override", "newProperty": "new property" }
```

Is there a way I can preserve the original name of the class in the console output?  E.g. I would like the output of that last console statement to be

```
Greeter2: { "property": "property", "hello": "override", "newProperty": "new property" }
```

All code samples available in the typescript sandbox [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBANgQwM4YCIFMJwBOaURAPACqK4AeUuYAJhogN6Ji4DuiAFAHSC0hAOYYAXIjRgAngG0AugEpJrAL6I1APl4AoRMgQYohENCKSKupW32JCuKCEJJUmFrXpMWBMMdPmhLYGBpxcAAqEcAAOuIRQMogAvIgARGGI0VGx8TKpANx2BgAWuCgocMlpcABucYQwjLgFdmqFarq6AAJuWHgExKSEur0sAOIOjnHBmdlxCVWpWTHzeYUlZRWS-jBgIuuGfiZmQ7wAttsmuyI2rEWIUMUwGPyl5ZUpZwcdHSNGcChcPwKiJeBkJrgpoReKkuEQUIxUkolIUAPSopJaNhpZY5BKpSRLOa5VIAGjSbwqBOqdUIDSaZLSYUiKxJhIyuNWqU0nVAkFgCGQ6D6%20CIJCIACZKNQ6AxmNiMgIhKIJFJZIoVGwNNo9AZfP4ThZEFZbnZ9VBEABZGT9MX0RgAYWFLBSoxlXnl5oCQxmoW4LLxiRS6W4s1Z%20IOG3ei1q9UazW%20BwcThcVptosGuEdzt0vx6zttg0lI2diAhUIlM05uUW1YjdkpcEuDT2By9huhF0QOz2ppCDyeL0bVS%20rVznX1AKBILBofL9EIEphcMICKRKN06Mx2KJ4byhLreXJqUb1NSsbp8cZIYixPx7NDh%205HSAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, seems a bit hacky though.

```
function classDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  const cls = class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
  };
  Object.defineProperty(cls, 'name', {
    get: () => `${constructor.name}Generated`
  });
  return cls
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that certainly works!  Is there a reason to prefer `{get: () => ...}` vs                       
`{value: \`${constructor.name}Generated\`, writeable: false}` ?

Comment: Update: both work to solve my problem with console.log, but oddly neither works in the vscode debugger (details in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64491766/239712 )