# vscode debugger with typescript: what determines how an object is rendered?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, console.log, vscode-debugger

I'm using vscode to write some typescript, and I have set a breakpoint. When I open the Debug pane and ask it to evaluate an object, what is it doing to produce the string representation?

The reason I am asking is because I am using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64474943/239712) to control the way that `console.log` renders an instance of a class, and it works great -- but it doesn't seem to impact the way the object is rendered in the debugger.

To be more specific, the below code (also available in the typescript sandbox [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBANgQwM4YCIFMJwBOaURAzADwAqiuAHlLmACYaIDeiYuA7ogBQA6YWkIBzDAC5EaMAE8A2gF0AlNPYBfRBoB8-AFCJkCDFEIhoRaVX0qOh42FPIUbALwvMbeoxZsCTmYWpIT2RkbcPAAKhHAADriEUHKIHgBEkYhxsQlJcmkA3A5GABa4KChwqYhpcABuiYQwzLiFDhpFRgDyAEYAVvhQgi3AMNwx8YnJ-KgYADSIAORgaAC2uIsL7MWIYrhQ0vx2bjqIAAYAJOwBpuaWhIIr6xoA4kyJJLjMZ+0qnYiEfYgQhIWb6DT6fQAAVQXjwBGIITI+lhWEQL0B+0SZDCWRyUxS6WykzybVK5Uq0luYzE-xuQXu-FWVLMNLs23CiCgJRgGEEZQqVQ8q3+EIhKJMUEQqzkvT61UyGNwWMIZH4aR4RBQzDSKglTjgKFwgkqYiZsv6f30AHprScjEqVWQ3txEV91DViblkmlpGkvQS0gs0gLKr6avVGs1WsHIhNvfk-ZkA6TtIggA)) results in the desired output from console.log.  However, when I set a breakpoint just before the `console.log` line and evaluate `myObj` in the debugger, what's displayed is

```
cls {property: 'property', hello: 'override', newProperty: 'new property'}
```

rather than

```
Greeter3Generated {property: 'property', hello: 'override', newProperty: 'new property'}
```

Code in question:

```js
function classDecorator3<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  const cls = class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
  };
  Object.defineProperty(cls, 'name', {
    get: () => `${constructor.name}Generated`
  });
  return cls
}

@classDecorator3
class Greeter3 {
  property = "property";
  hello: string;
  constructor(m: string) {
    this.hello = m;
  }
}

const myObj = new Greeter3("world")
console.log(myObj);
//=>  Greeter3Generated: { "property": "property", "hello": "override", "newProperty": "new property" }
```

Comment: what happens if you set the `name` property to a literal string in the decorator, maybe the debugger will not call a method for the class name

Comment: try a `data descriptor` with `value` property that is a literal string, not a backtick string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Symbol/toStringTag). Also, you can remove the hack which overrides the native `constructor.name`:

```
function classDecorator3<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  return class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
    [Symbol.toStringTag] = `${constructor.name}Generated`;
  };
}

@classDecorator3
class Greeter3 {
  property = "property";
  hello: string;
  constructor(m: string) {
    this.hello = m;
  }
}

const myObj = new Greeter3("world");
console.log(myObj);
//=>  Greeter3Generated: { "property": "property", "hello": "override", "newProperty": "new property" }
```

Demo with plain JavaScript (to execute with developer tools opened):

```js
function classDecorator3(
  constructor
) {
  return class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
    [Symbol.toStringTag] = `${constructor.name}Generated`;
  };
}

const GeneratedClass = classDecorator3(class Greeter3 {
  property = "property";
  hello;
  constructor(m) {
    this.hello = m;
  }
});

const myObj = new GeneratedClass("world");
console.log(myObj);
debugger;
```

Result in Node.js:

[image: Result in Node.js]

Comment: Works beautifully in the VSCode debugger thank you!!  But one detail -- when I remove the override of `constructor.name` the console.log statement looks like `cls: {...}`.  When I put it back, I get `Greeter3Generated: {...}` as desired.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the result in Node.js for me (v12.18.3). You don't have this on your side?

Comment: When overriding the class constructor within the decorator, setting `[Symbol.toStringTag]` does not work - i got the error: `A 'super' call must be the first statement in the constructor when a class contains initialized properties, parameter properties, or private identifiers.`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @derdeka just do what it asks